# What is the default unit of time for time()?

Tags: php, time, default-value

I have code that looks like this:

```
$CreateTimeFrom = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",time()-20000)
```

But what does that -20000 mean? Is that 20000 seconds prior? Or minutes? What is the default value?

Comment: This is easily research-able and testable.

Answer (score 2):

It's in seconds, because [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns a unix timestamp, which is the amount of seconds since jan 1 1970.

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of **seconds** that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), January 1, 1970.

Comment: January 1, 1970, is the Unix epoch, if you wanted to know. :)

Comment: Yeah, and it's pretty annoying and confusing (especially when coding low-level time-related stuff) that [many of them call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) a _point_ in time "epoch", while [its natural meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epoch) is a _duration_.

Answer (score 1):

It means 20000 seconds (See [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) and `time()` returns a unix timestamp.

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time,
>   defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), January 1, 1970

- 1 minute = 60
- 1 hour = 3600
- 1 Day = 24 * 3600

Answer (score 0):

`time()` is the very last second of the current date. 
`time()-20000` is current clock time minus 20000 seconds, so 333,33 minutes earlier.

If you encounter unexpected results, then its worth the check

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```